# hashtag boundaries matching regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match, matching

I'm trying to match a set of hashtags or words in a javascript string.

```
(#hashtag|word)
```

almost does it, except I'd like to consider word boundaries.

```
\b(#hashtag|word)\b
```

doesn't match the beginning word boundary, since of course '#' is not a word character.

ideally i'd like to have something like a '\b' anchor that matches hashtags. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. A few input-result examples would be helpful.

Comment: input:"my tweet that contains a #hashtag and a keyword"
i'd like to match '#hastag' and 'keyword'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about insert word boundary inside the parenths :

```
/(#\bhashtag|\bword)\b/
```

Comment: nice! but...
input: "a#hashtag".
it matches the '#hashtag' part, but i would only like the match to occur when there is a string beginning or a space character before it.

Comment: Try this one : /(\B#hashtag|\bword)\b/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Twitter's official regular expression for recognizing hashtags here it is.

The source code used to generate it is here: https://gist.github.com/hansineffect/9629263

```
/(#|＃)([a-z0-9_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f]*[a-z_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f][a-z0-9_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f]*)/gi
```