# Javascript Regex Word Boundary with optional non-word character

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I am looking to find a keyword match in a string. I am trying to use word boundary, but this may not be the best case for that solution. The keyword could be any word, and could be preceded with a non-word character. The string could be any string at all and could include all three of these words in the array, but I should only match on the keyword:

```
['hello', '#hello', '@hello'];
```

Here is my code, which includes an attempt found in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119023/hashtag-boundaries-matching-regex-in-javascript):

```
let userStr = 'why hello there, or should I say #hello there?';

let keyword = '#hello';

let re = new RegExp(`/(#\b${userStr})\b/`);

re.exec(keyword);
```

- This would be great if the string always started with #, but it does not.
- I then tried this `/(#?\b${userStr})\b/`, but if the string does start with `#`, it tries to match `##hello`.
- The `matchThis` str could be any of the 3 examples in the array, and the userStr may contain several variations of the `matchThis` but only one will be exact

Comment: You need something like `new RegExp(\`(^|\\W)(${keyword})(?!\\w)\`)`. Are you extracting or replacing? Or just testing for a match?

Comment: You don't include the `/` delimiters when you use `new RegExp`

Comment: Shouldn't the keyword be in the regular expression, not the user string?

Comment: @Barmar The description is just out of sync with the code snippet. However, the description seems to be consistent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am extracting.

Comment: @Barmar sorry about the confusion, the description is probably clearer than my code right now

Comment: See my answer. If you need any adjustment, please drop a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the answer. Is there a more elegant solution without `while`? Maybe a match group rather than word boundary?

Comment: @jmcgui05 Do you need to get *all* matches? Then `while` with `RegExp#exec` is the most elegant. Others are workarounds.

Comment: @jmcgui05 [Look here to see one of the workarounds](http://jsfiddle.net/xLzfhjam/). Note the loop is still there, inside the `.replace`, you just do not "see" it.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for clarifying. I will just need to find one match in the string

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for 3 things here:

- The main point is that a `\b` word boundary is a context-dependent construct, and if your input is not always alphanumeric-only, you need unambiguous word boundaries
- You need to double escape special chars inside constructor RegExp notation
- As you pass a variable to a regex, you need to make sure all special chars are properly escaped.

Use

```js
let userStr = 'why hello there, or should I say #hello there?';
let keyword = '#hello';
let re_pattern = `(?:^|\\W)(${keyword.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})(?!\\w)`;
let res = [], m;

// To find a single (first) match
console.log((m=new RegExp(re_pattern).exec(userStr)) ? m[1] : "");

// To find multiple matches:
let rx = new RegExp(re_pattern, "g");
while (m=rx.exec(userStr)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern description**

- `(?:^|\\W)` - a non-capturing string matching the start of string or any non-word char
- `(${keyword.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})` - Group 1: a *keyword* value with escaped special chars
- `(?!\\w)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the keyword already begins with a special character. If it does, don't include it in the regular expression.

```
var re;
if ("#@".indexOf(keyword[0]) == -1) {
    re = new RegExp(`[@#]?\b${keyword}\b`);
} else {
    re = new RegExp(`\b${keyword}\b`);
}
```